# PHP MYSQL : IF Statement (Comparing data from select statement) (Error: Displaying Nothing)

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have a php code like this :

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT movie_tittle, sinopsis, actors, poster
                     FROM (SELECT movie_tittle, sinopsis, actors,
                         poster, cinema from `margoplatinum`.movie
                     UNION
                     SELECT movie_tittle, sinopsis, actors, poster, cinema 
                        from `detos21`.movie
                     UNION
                     SELECT movie_tittle, sinopsis, actors, poster, cinema 
                        from `plaza21`.movie) AS a
                     WHERE a.movie_tittle = "Comic 8"');

IF ( 'cinema' == "Margo Platinum") {

 $json  = '{"film": [';

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $char = '"';

        $json .='{
        "movie_tittle":"'.str_replace($char,'`',strip_tags($row["movie_tittle"])).'",
        "sinopsis":"'.str_replace($char,'`',strip_tags($row["sinopsis"])).'",
        "actors":"'.str_replace($char,'`',strip_tags($row["actors"])).'",
        "poster":"http://10.0.2.2/cinemainfo/margoplatinum/image/'.$row["poster"].'"},';

    }
$json = substr($json,0,strlen($json)-1);

$json .= ']}';

// print json
echo $json;
}

 IF ( 'cinema' == "21 Delta Town Square") {

$json  = '{"film": [';

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $char = '"';

        $json .='{
        "movie_tittle":"'.str_replace($char,'`',strip_tags($row["movie_tittle"])).'",
        "sinopsis":"'.str_replace($char,'`',strip_tags($row["sinopsis"])).'",
        "actors":"'.str_replace($char,'`',strip_tags($row["actors"])).'",
        "poster":"http://10.0.2.2/cinemainfo/detos21/image/'.$row["poster"].'"},';

    }
$json = substr($json,0,strlen($json)-1);

$json .= ']}';

// print json
echo $json;
}

 IF ( 'cinema' == "21 Plaza") {

$json  = '{"film": [';

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $char = '"';

        $json .='{
        "movie_tittle":"'.str_replace($char,'`',strip_tags($row["movie_tittle"])).'",
        "sinopsis":"'.str_replace($char,'`',strip_tags($row["sinopsis"])).'",
        "actors":"'.str_replace($char,'`',strip_tags($row["actors"])).'",
        "poster":"http://10.0.2.2/cinemainfo/plaza21/image/'.$row["poster"].'"},';

    }
$json = substr($json,0,strlen($json)-1);

$json .= ']}';

// print json
echo $json;
}
```

I have three databases and I would like to get some data from them. So I use `UNION` clauses. It works with the other php code.

So now, I fetch data from select statement and i want to compare the data from `cinema` column with string like e.g. `"Margo Platinum"` , If `True`, then convert into `JSON` code. 
But the problem is, when I execute that code, it returns nothing to display. 
Is that code correct? 
Please, help me to write the correct one :(
I really appreciate any help from you.
Thank you :)

Comment: `'cinema' == "Margo Platinum"` (etc) will never be true

Comment: IF ( 'cinema' == "Margo Platinum") - what is this?

Comment: are you talking with computer...? :)

Comment: cinema is the field, and "Margo Platinum" is the string that I want to compare..If the field `cinema` = "margo platinum" then blabla bla

Comment: @RC. So how to write the correct one? Can you give me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Grrr. I can't comment on above, so have to write an answer.
The above guys already gave you your answer, just a little convoluted.
By having

```
'cinema' == "Margo Platinum"
```

you're just comparing two strings,so it's never going to equal true and that's why your code within that condition does nothing.

I note you are also using mysql_query and mysql_fetch_array which is deprecated. You may want to use mysqli_query and mysqli_fetch_array.
I also don't see anywhere where you are putting the results of the cinema column into a variable called cinema, but I'm not that familiar with json.

Whatever the case, you're comparing two strings which just ain't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution (not tested):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT movie_tittle, sinopsis, actors, poster, 'margoplatinum' AS code
                     FROM `margoplatinum`.movie
                     UNION
                     SELECT movie_tittle, sinopsis, actors, poster, 'detos21' AS code
                     FROM `detos21`.movie
                     UNION
                     SELECT movie_tittle, sinopsis, actors, poster, 'plaza21' AS code
                     FROM `plaza21`.movie
                     WHERE movie_tittle = 'Comic 8'");

$json  = '{"film": [';

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $char = '"';
    $json .='{
        "movie_tittle":"'.str_replace($char,'`',strip_tags($row["movie_tittle"])).'",
        "sinopsis":"'.str_replace($char,'`',strip_tags($row["sinopsis"])).'",
        "actors":"'.str_replace($char,'`',strip_tags($row["actors"])).'",
        "poster":"http://10.0.2.2/cinemainfo/' . $row["code"] . '/image/'.$row["poster"].'"},';
}
$json = substr($json,0,strlen($json)-1);
$json .= ']}';

// print json
echo $json;
```